# Set value to a hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an instant search program which was collected from a [tutorial](http://www.codeforest.net/simple-search-with-php-jquery-and-mysql)
. I modified some lines of the code. Here is the document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".search_button").click(function() {
                // getting the value that user typed
                var searchString    = $("#search_box").val();
                // forming the queryString
                var data            = 'search='+ searchString;

                // if searchString is not empty
                if(searchString) {
                    // ajax call
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "instant_search.php",
                        data: data,
                        beforeSend: function(html) { // this happens before actual call
                            $(".results").html('');
                            //$("#uname").value('');
                            //$("#searchresults").show();
                            $(".word").html(searchString);
                        },
                        success: function(html){ // this happens after we get results
                            $(".results").show();
                            $(".results").append(html);
                            $('#uname').value(html);
                            //document.getElementById('uname').value(html);
                            //$("#uname").value(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<center>';?>

    <div class="header_box"><?php echo $f->SYSTEM_NAME; ?></div>

<?php
if($acc_type == 'admin'){ ?>
    <h1>Create new admin account</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" size="20" class="text_box"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Check"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
}else if($acc_type == 'student'){ ?>
    <h1>.:: Create student's account ::.</h1>
    <label style="font-size: 18px"><label style="color: red">*</label> Marked fields are must</label><br/><br/>
<!--    <form action="" method="post">-->
    <table border="0">
        <tr class="unimportant_text">
            <td>Test Username</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="instant_search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class="unimportant_text"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="search_button" value="Check" style="background: #808080; color: white; border: none"/><br />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username<label style="color: red">*</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <label class="results" style="font-size: 20px; color: green; font-weight: bold"></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="uname" id="uname"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Full Name<label style="color: red">*</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="text_box"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact<label style="color: red">*</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="text_box" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact (Optional)</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="text_box" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="text_box" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Course<label style="color: red">*</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="course">
                    <?php
                    $courses = $f->get_courses();
                    foreach($courses as $c){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $c[1];?>"><?php echo $c[1];?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="text_box" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<!--    </form>-->
    <?php
}
?>
<?php echo '</center>';?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my instant_search.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$res = $f->select_name($word);
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    //echo 'Not available, choose another one';
} else {
    echo $word;
}
}
```

What I want is very simple.

1. I just want to check if the `$word` is available in database. If not then set that as value of a hidden field(uname). Then submit the form to another php file and create the account.
2. Here two form is being used, this is creating problem as well.

Please help me doing the job. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what is the problem you are facing instead of asking for the whole solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a specific code from PHP and test it in the success callback of your AJAX call.

instant_search :

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $res = $f - > select_name($word);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        //The word is not in DB, then specify error in front of it
        echo '[error]'.$word;
    } else {
        echo $word;
    }
}
```

In your success callback :

```
success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
    if(html.search('[error]') >= 0)
    {
       //Error : set your input field with returned text
       $('#uname').val(html.split('[error]')[1]);

       //Call your second form here           
    }
    else
    {
        //No error
        $(".results").show();
        $(".results").append(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set value to the hidden element if no error

Comment: I modified your code. And works for me. Thank you